# Programatically load orders of data changed in magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, programmatically, data

Can anyone help me how to load the data edited orders in magento1.9.

Please help me if any one have idea about this.

Thanks

Comment: I didn't get your question , please ask more clear

Comment: if i edit the order information like items, qty  get those orders

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't check below code but this should work please check and let me know as well

You can check created_at and updated_at date if those are not equal then some data changed after some time

```
 $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
 $orders->getSelect()->where('created_at<>updated_at');
```

Comment: ok thanks for your info @Murtuza, i will check it and update to you.

Comment: What is this mean:where('created_at<>updated_at')

Comment: @shivashankarm 'not equal' that's mysql syntax

Comment: but i want the updated orders and items edited orders

Comment: iam getting some orders but those are not exist in magento